# Failed connect to Oracle using DataGrip with OCI DLLs

Tags: oracle, datagrip

I would love to get DataGrip 1.0.3 on Win7 x64 to connect to our `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0` which I've successfully worked with from various versions of PL/SQL Developer.

First of all I notice the auto-completion of the "TNS name" field in the "Data Sources and Drivers" dialog offering only some of the Oracle Instance names listed in `tnsnames.ora` file which DataGrip finds via the TNS_ADMIN directory I specify.

When I choose an offered "TNS name", along with a known-good username & password, I can't connect due to this error:

> Native library cannot be loaded.
>
> C:\ProgramData\IPGM\OraPGM64\ORACLE\Client11gR2\bin\ocijdbc11.dll:
>   Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
>
> C:\ProgramData\IPGM\OraPGM64\ORACLE\Client11gR2\bin\ocijdbc11.dll:
>   Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform

When I try to modify the shortcut for starting DataGrip to point to `datagrip64.exe`, and also when I try to set the PATH to `OraPGM32` instead of `OraPGM64`, I get this error instead:

> Native library cannot be loaded.
>
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.getLibraryVersionNumber()I
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.getLibraryVersionNumber()I

I've looked at the [help pages](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/help/getting-started-with-datagrip.html) and googled. Any hints appreciated!

Comment: Found  [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=%23DataGrip+%23Oracle+) for DataGrip  and `C:\Users\myuser\.DataGrip10\system\log\idea.log` to continue investigation...

Comment: Created [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2407) on YouTrack.

Comment: Hey, did you solve?

Comment: Not sure: I do not have an Oracle anymore. I noticed that the YouTrack issue was recently closed as obsolete with comment `Shall work now as 32-bit bundles are dropped.`

Comment: I asked because I'm trying to configure the OCI driver. I'm using the JDBC Thin driver now, but it gives me problems.

Comment: I couldn't make it work back then. Maybe you can find corresponding or create new issue on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=%23DataGrip+%23Oracle+). If you run into similar problems as I did, reference my [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2407)